# How to trigger update in another model when a different model changes in Rails, Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an **Episode** and a **Playlist**.
**Episode** and **Playlist** have seconds and **Episode** has many **Playlists** and **Playlist** has many **Episodes**.

The seconds of **Playlist** are a sum of the seconds in its **Episodes**

**Question**: How to update the seconds of a **Playlist** when the seconds in **Episode** changes?

(I know this denormalizes the db, but the advantages are more)

What have I done&

1. Observers -> they seem to be deprecated?
2. Callbacks -> it means I should add logic to **Episode** which is wrong because this logic concerns only **Playlist**. No additional logic should be added in **Episode**
3. Wisper -> More than half an hour already in wisper and wisper-activerecord and I still can receive any events. Plus it is again adding logic to the **Episode**, because you should do Episode.subscribe(Playlist.new) which is actually Publisher.subscribe(Listener.new). I can't see the logic of why the Publisher subscribes the Listener to events that are important to the Listener. It should be the Listener subscribing to events, but this is not wisper idea?
4. ActiveSupport::Notifications -> as I get it their idea is instrumentation not communication between models.

Comment: My approach would be to create a Service.
Use the Service from your Episodes-controller, trigger the update-event, if it succeeds => trigger update for Playlist.

The Service should not depend on any models or AR.
Headline 2 shows an example:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Did you mean to say "Episode belongs to Playlist"?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Technically there is Library model as an intermediate. Episode has_many Libraries. Playlist has_many Libraries. Library belongs_to Episode and Playlist. But the goal is for Episode to be in many Playlists and a Playlist to have many Episodes